# click gets detected when function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function reset_all_lightbox_assets()
{
    $(document).one("click", function () {  
        $("#lightbox-asset-wrapdiv .category-asset-div-tileview").css({"background-color": "#f9f9f9"});
        $("#lightbox-asset-wrapdiv .category-asset-table-td-category,#lightbox-asset-wrapdiv .category-asset-table-td-id").css("color", "#777777");
        $("#lightbox-asset-wrapdiv .category-asset-table-td-name").css("color", "#999999");
    });
}
```

When this function is called I want to be able to click the document once and execute the code.

The problem is that when the function is called, it also immediately detects the click. So how can I call the function so the click becomes enabled but only gets executed when I actually click again?

Comment: with bind i get the same problem, with live it doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `event.stopPropagation()` in the click handler that calls `reset_all_lightbox_assets()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try standard addEventListener instead:

```
element.addEventListener('click',doSomething,false)
```

[quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. 1st click: bind click handlers
2. 2nd click: unbind **old** click handler
3. 2nd click: do job
4. 2nd click: unbind **new** working click handler

Code

```
$(document).on("click", function () {  
     // First click do nothing
     // Unbind old click listener
     $(document).unbind('click');
     // Now add your listener
     $(document).on("click", function () {  
          $("#lightbox-asset-wrapdiv .category-asset-div-tileview").css({"background-color": "#f9f9f9"});
          $("#lightbox-asset-wrapdiv .category-asset-table-td-category,#lightbox-asset-wrapdiv .category-asset-table-td-id").css("color", "#777777");
          $("#lightbox-asset-wrapdiv .category-asset-table-td-name").css("color", "#999999");
     });
     // 2nd click listeners unbind
     $(document).unbind('click');
});
```